bash script to launch multiple instances of vifm
I'm using Mint (virginia) and i3wm. I want a script that launches 4 instances of vifm in each quadrant of the screen.
#!/bin/bash

declare -a split=("i3-msg splitv" "i3-msg splith" "i3-msg splitv" "i3-msg splith")

for y in "${split[@]}"; do
    echo "$y"
    kitty bash -c vifm &
done

I used the above script and got 4 windows but they were all split horizontally
ok so I tried this too but it didn't work:
#!/bin/bash
                                                                                               
declare -a split=("splitv" "splith" "splitv" "splith")

for y in "${split[@]}"; do
   kitty bash -c "vifm" && "i3-msg ${y}" & 
done


Does kitty need those split values? I'm not familiar with the tool but I don't understand how it's supposed to do something different if you run four identical commands.

It might help to make it work by hand if you know how to do that, then show the working commands vs your non-working script.

yeah the split values are needed to get vifm in quadrants of the screen. Normally on the cl you issue vifm then use keyboard ctrl-v or ctrl-h to set orientation of split or you can use i3-msg splitv or splith from the cli

This seems to have everything to do with how kitty or i3-msg works, and nothing to do with vifm specifically.

Does i3-msg need to be run in the shell started by bash -c? Then it should be kitty bash -c "vifm && i3-msg $y" &

yeah that didn't work either :(

@chepner you are right I think, this has something to do with how i3-msg works; I can get 4 instances of vifm but they're either all hsplit or vsplit--can't get i3-msg to work while in mid-loop.. :(
